# Ordenar pelo maior ID e agrupar os semelhantes

Tags: mysql, sql

Como posso listar os registros, ordenando pelo último, mas quando tiver o campo `related` preenchido, trazer os outros registros com esse mesmo valor?

A ideia geral é fazer um `order by id desc` e agrupar os relacionados.

Minha tabela está assim:

```
ID  TITLE       RELATED
1   tenis       null
2   camiseta    123456
3   calca       null
4   moletom     123456
5   casaco      null
```

O correto seria listar assim: listando pelo maior `ID`, mas quando tem o campo `related`, da prioridade para os outros registros que possuem o mesmo valor que ele.

```
ID  TITLE       RELATED
5   casaco      null
4   moletom     123456
2   camiseta    123456
3   calca       null
1   tenis       null
```

Comment: Não me parece que isso se consiga fazer com uma _query_ "simples". Terá de haver aí alguma lógica intermédia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ficam aqui duas alternativas:

A primeira consiste em usar uma junção (com a própria tabela). Esta é uma solução portável, visto que apenas usa elementos ou funcionalidades standard da linguagem SQL, e que estão disponíveis em (quase) todos os sistemas de gestão de base de dados.

```
SELECT P1.*
  FROM produtos P1
  LEFT JOIN 
  ( 
     SELECT RELATED, MAX(ID) MAX_ID 
       FROM produtos 
      WHERE RELATED IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY RELATED
  ) AS P2
    ON P2.related = P1.RELATED
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN P2.RELATED IS NULL THEN P1.ID ELSE P2.MAX_ID END DESC, P1.ID DESC
```

A ideia passa por identificar os produtos para os quais existe informação na coluna RELATED, e para cada um dos códigos RELATED identificar qual o ID máximo correspondente. Esta informação será usada como critério de ordenação da seguinte forma:

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN P2.RELATED IS NULL THEN P1.ID ELSE P2.MAX_ID END DESC`

O resultado, será aquele que indicou na sua pergunta:

```
| ID  | TITLE    | RELATED |
| --- | -------- | ------- |
| 5   | casaco   |         | 
| 4   | moletom  | 123456  |
| 2   | camiseta | 123456  |
| 3   | calca    |         |
| 1   | tenis    |         |
```

A segunda alternativa, faz uso das funções de janela disponiveis nas versões mais recentes do MySQL.

```
SELECT ID,
       TITLE,
       RELATED,
       MAX(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN RELATED IS NOT NULL THEN RELATED ELSE ID END) AS SortingOrder
  FROM produtos
ORDER BY 4 DESC, ID DESC
;
```

O resultado será o mesmo da versão anterior.

```
| ID  | TITLE    | RELATED | SortingOrder |
| --- | -------- | ------- | ------------ |
| 5   | casaco   |         | 5            |
| 4   | moletom  | 123456  | 4            |
| 2   | camiseta | 123456  | 4            |
| 3   | calca    |         | 3            |
| 1   | tenis    |         | 1            |
```

Comment: Perfeito! Só uma observação, na primeira alternativa só foi preciso remover a parte "AS SORTING_ORDER". Pode ser pq estou usando a versão 5.7.

Comment: Tem razão, foi uma erro de copy-paste. Já alterei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, 
       title, 
       related 
  FROM produtos
 ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN related IS NULL 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END, related;
```

Resultado:

> id         title           related
>
> ---
>
> 2           camiseta        123456
>
> 4           moletom         123456
>
> 1           tenis           NULL
>
> 3           calca           NULL
>
> 5           casaco          NULL

(5 linha(s) afetadas)

Não é possível classificar desse jeito que você quer, pois a classificação segue
uma hierarquia o SQL classifica o  COD e dentro do cod classifica related
mas se você o principal objetivo for o agrupamento do related e em orderm descendente
talvez te ajude.

ou isso ajuda

```
SELECT title,
       related,
       cod 
  FROM produtos
 ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN related IS NULL 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END, related, cod DESC;
```

> title           related     cod
>
> ---
>
> moletom         123456      4
>
> camiseta        123456      2
>
> casaco          NULL        5
>
> calca           NULL        3
>
> tenis           NULL        1

(5 linha(s) afetadas)